# How to assign a dynamic value to input List property in angular

Tags: html, .net, angularjs, typescript

I want to render multiple dropdowns in angular based on the result from api.
From the api 2 dropdown controls are returned with different data however my code shows same data for both of the controls

Can anyone suggest how to assign a dynamic value to the property "list" in the input element?. I think if that is possible my problem would be solved or please let me know if there is any other solution

Comment: <input id="{{cntrl.id}}" list="cntrl.itemListType"/> i mean the list property in the input tag. Can we assign a value to it at run time like id

Answer (score 1):

As `list` is an [*input attribute* not a property](http://%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-list), you can assign dynamic value to list using:

`[attr.list] ='object.property'`.

for more info [see the issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12759)